# Error in R CMD SHLIB compiling C code

Tags: c, r, cmd

I am trying to use **R CMD SHLIB** for a **C** program written using **Lapack** and **Blas**. I am using the command prompt in Windows. But it seems unable to link to the external libraries. How can I link these libraries?

```
D:\R\testR>Rcmd SHLIB fmpc.c
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o fmpc.dll tmp.def fmpc.o
-Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/x64 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -L
D:/R/R-3.3.2/bin/x64 -lR
fmpc.o:fmpc.c:(.text+0x76d): undefined reference to `dposv_'
fmpc.o:fmpc.c:(.text+0x800): undefined reference to `dtrtrs_'
fmpc.o:fmpc.c:(.text+0x83b): undefined reference to `dtrtrs_'
fmpc.o:fmpc.c:(.text+0x92f): undefined reference to `dposv_'
fmpc.o:fmpc.c:(.text+0x9bf): undefined reference to `dtrtrs_'
fmpc.o:fmpc.c:(.text+0x9fa): undefined reference to `dtrtrs_'
fmpc.o:fmpc.c:(.text+0xb19): undefined reference to `dgemm_'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a *linker* error and not a *compiler* error.  The compilation step passed fine.

Solution: Tell R to link against the missing library, most by adding a file `src/Makevars.win` with the following:

```
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

It is a variable declaration using other variable which R knows.

Comment: So I did add this line to the **Makevars.win** under the R directory. However, it gives me the same error. Do I need to execute another line in Command Prompt to link? Do I need to put/download those libraries somewhere?

Comment: It has to be a file `Makevars.win` in the directory `src` as indicated by the shorthand notation `src/Makevars.win` I employed in my answer.  You used the wrong directory.

Comment: I have two src folders:  **D:/R/R-3.3.2/src/Makevars.win**    and     **D:/R/R-3.3.2/src/library/windlgs/src/Makevars.win**     I put the makefile in both folders. Still it cannot link. My 'Makevars.win' has this content: **PKG_LIBS = $(GRAPHAPP_LIB)
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)**

Comment: No need to yell with bold markup, in any event we prefer backticks to typeset `as code`.  All you need to know is in the [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) manual.  There are now over 10,000 packages on CRAN, and several thousand of these use compiled source.  So why not read the manual and study existing working examples?